# uso de conmutadores

Tags: javascript

Estoy utilizando con Bootstrap la palanca (on,off), pero no logro enlazarla con la base de datos mediante PHP.

Aqui tengo la llamada a la funcion changeState y le paso dos parametros como son:
- identificador
- activo o inactivo (0,1)

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-slider--b-flat">
 <label>
 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onChange="changeState(<?=$site['id']?>,<?=$site['active']?>)">
<span>Activo</span>
 </label>
</div>

function changeState(id,nuevo) 
{
 window.location.href = '?page=pages&p='+pagina+'&changestate&id='+id+'&nuevo='+nuevo;
}
```

La pregunta es que a partir de aqui desearia cambiar el estado de dos de mis variables en la db que son 'id' y 'nuevo'.

Podria ser capturando la ruta en concreto que se visualiza al apretar el control 'checkbox' o por otro metodo?